# Why is Nexus staging ignoring the Maven deploy flag?

Tags: java, maven, nexus

In a parent POM I have Nexus staging enabled (with the Sonatype repositories in distribution management):

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
          <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>

  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

I deploy projects to Maven Central all the time using this parent POM.

However today I have a project that uses an aggregate POM, and I wanted to deploy it and its aggregated projects *except for two of them* to Maven Central. So I put the following in the two subproject aggregate child POMs which I did *not* want to deploy:

```
<properties>
  <maven.deploy.skip>true</maven.deploy.skip>
</properties>
```

Then (still using a SNAPSHOT version) I attempted to deploy to the snapshot repository as a test:

```
mvn clean deploy
```

This is the error I got:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy (injected-nexus-deploy)
    on project foo-bar: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.example:foo-bar:war.asc:0.1.0-…
    from/to ossrh (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots): Access denied to:
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/example/foo-bar/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/foo-bar-0.1.0-….war.asc -> [Help 1]
```

I don't understand the "access denied" part. But the bigger question is why Nexus is trying to deploy my `foo-bar` project for which I had set `maven.deploy.skip` to `false`?

*Update:* There seem to be several interrelated issues here.

First of all, the "access denied" part was my fault: I had neglected to coordinate with Sonatype to add a new group ID with permissions to publish to Maven Central for this project.

Afterwards, however, even though there is no "access denied", Maven still deploys all the projects, even the ones with `maven.deploy.skip` to `false`. Someone mentioned that `maven.deploy.skip` is meant for the `maven-deploy-plugin` and not the `nexus-staging-maven-plugin`. OK, then, so that leaves two remaining questions:

- I have another project in which I set `maven.deploy.skip` to `false` for the *aggregate* POM, but then set it back to `true` for the aggregated child POM. Maven correctly deployed only the aggregated child POM, and did *not* deploy the aggregate parent POM to Maven Central. So why does the `maven.deploy.skip` seem to work even for the `nexus-staging-maven-plugin` if disabled on an aggregate parent POM, but not for an aggregated child POM?
- OK then, so if `maven.deploy.skip` is not the answer, how *do* I disable deployment to Maven Central for an aggregate child POM by modifying the aggregate child POM? (I know I can remove the child POM from the aggregate POM's list of modules, but this would result in a different aggregate parent POM being deployed.)

Comment: Have you checked your settings.xml file in .m2 folder? Shoud have some username and password.

Comment: @Calixto, how is that in any way related to the question? Can you explain how the presence or absence of a username/password in the `setting.xml` file would have any bearing on the circumstances described?

Comment: If I understand correctlly the plugin are trying to "transfer artifact"  from/to ossrh. Maybe you need some permition to do that. If is not, let me know and I can delete my comment. Just trying to help.

Comment: But @Calixto, if I told it to skip deployment for that POM, why would it even be _attempting_ to deploy that artifact? (Did you read the question closely?)

Comment: The point is the flag `maven.deploy.skip` is intended for `maven-deploy-plugin` and not for the nexus-staging-maven-plugin....

Answer (score 0):

> But the bigger question is why Nexus is trying to deploy my foo-bar project for which I had set maven.deploy.skip to false?

Because you're saying you don't want to skip, the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) says that the value is `false` by default, so setting it to that doesn't change anything from the default behavior.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. The actual POM says `true`. I'll edit the question.